# Google Apps Script Formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Firstly apologies for poor etiquette or dumb questions, this is my first foray into scripting on a google spreadsheet and I must say I'm struggling more than with VBA in excel. Anyway to my problem;

I have a spreadsheet with four columns and fifty three rows. The columns hold; Week Number (eg 33), Week Commencing Date (eg 13/08/12), Hours Worked (eg 31:15:00) and Pay Due (eg $150.00).
The first row has the headings and rows 2 to 53 are the weeks of the year.
Too easy campese. Now I have managed to write a script that when run will email me a summary email for week. My code is as follows;

```
  function sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Summary");
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;   // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, sheet.getLastColumn());
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  //Logger.log(data)

  for (i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var date = new Date();
    var sheetDate = new Date(row[1]);
    Sdate=Utilities.formatDate(date,'GMT-1000','w')  
    SsheetDate=Utilities.formatDate(sheetDate,'GMT-1000', 'w')
    //Logger.log(Sdate+' =? '+SsheetDate)
    if (Sdate == SsheetDate){
      var emailAddress = row[0];  // First column
      var weeknum = row[0];
      var week = row[1];
      var hours = row[2];
      var pay = row[3];
      var subject = "Timesheet Report for Week " + weeknum;
      MailApp.sendEmail('me@myemail.com', 
                        subject, 
                        "Chris, \n\nBased on the timesheet data you have submitted last week So and So has recorded the following hours and should be due the calculated pay.\n\n" +
                        "Week Beginning; " + week +
                        "\n\nTotal Hours Worked For The Week; " + hours +
                        "\n\nPay Due For The Week; " + pay);
     //Logger.log('SENT :'+emailAddress+'  '+subject+'  '+message)
    }    
  }
}
```

My problem now is I want week beginning to show "Monday 13th August", Total hours worked to show the time and Pay to show as currency. However the script does not retain the formatting from the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way in Apps Script to get the spreadsheet visual formatted cells, only the real values behind them. There's the `getNumberFormat` method, where you can get any specific formatting the user may have applied to a cell. But this method does not work as desired, since it fails to retrieve the correct formats for a lot of situations, e.g. currencies and percent values, and also does not retrieve the default formats, it's only if the user changed them.

In your case it might be easier just to format your values in the code itself since you're concatenating them manually. To format dates you can use [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#formatDate), and for number you probably can work yourself out with plain javascript functions, as `num.toFixed()` and some string concatenation for your currency symbols.

By the way, I have developed a script that does mail merge and have such formatting capabilities, you may find that it suit you better than this snippet. It's called FormEmailer and is available on the Script Gallery and [its site](http://sites.google.com/site/formemailer).

Comment: Thank you Henrique, I have followed your advice and now have the desired result. Thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: The `There's no way in Apps Script to get the spreadsheet visual formatted cells, only the real values behind them.` statement is not correct. It is possible to get and set the cell value format by using the `getNumberFormat`, `setNumberFormat`, `getNumberFormats` and `setNumberFormats` of the [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range) class. Also there are other functions to change font, background, formula, etc.

Comment: @megabyte1024 have you ever tried to use these functions? You'll very quickly find that they fall short in so many cases, that they're not really useful, e.g. what's the default date format of the spreadsheet (which may be configured with different locales). Try also to get currency and percent formats! All "default" formatting is lost with `getNumberFormat`. Only those applied manually are retrievable. No, you definitely never tried to format an array of values on Apps Script to look like the spreadsheet. There really should be a method `getVisualValues` that returns everything as strings.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use them before I wrote this comment. I set a custom format for a few cells in a spreadsheet and after in a script copied formats from the formatted cells to cells without format. It works fine. The impossibility to retrieve default formats - is not discussable, in fact there is no way, but the topic starter did not ask this. And this impossibility does not mean `There's no way....`. Let's be precise. There is a way to get the preformatted cells and no possibility to retrieve the default formats. To be continue.

Comment: Part2. Many people will read your answer and they will think that indeed there is no way to get formats for either formatted or not cells.

Comment: I'll update my answer just to avoid confusion. But I did not said that is is not possible to get the formats. I said it is not possible to get the formatted values that the user see on his screen. And I don't know any viable workaround to even format the values on the script itself. It is impossible. Half a solution is no solution at all!

Comment: I wrote ONLY about the mentioned statement. There is a confusion and I pointed this. That's all.

Comment: Henrique Abreu's point is very clear. As of today, there is NO way to get a cell's formatted value as a string. It's very frustrating! The moment you start digging further you discover all kinds of limitations with GAS.